# How to use resourceIdMatches to return a UiCollection

Tags: webdriver, appium, android-uiautomator

I'm writing some Appium Tests and I'm running into an issue where I need to select a bunch of UiElements that all start with "favorite_star-" and then a number (so favorite_start-0, favorite_star-1, etc).

I'm trying to use PageObjects to select these all into a UiCollection using the following:

```
[FindsByAndroidUIAutomator(AndroidUIAutomator = "new UiCollection().resourceIdMatches(\"favorite_star-\\d.\")", Priority = 1)]
private List<IMobileElement<AppiumWebElement>> favoriteStarList;
```

This doesn't seem to work, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Instead of using resourcematchesid...just use resourceid in a loop and increment an iterator to get each one and store each one in a uicollection

Comment: That's an option, but it can't be done using PageObjects, which is what I'd really like to use.